# Trouble integrating variable into complex regex in for loop?

Tags: python, regex, loops

I'm trying to construct code where I look at the next few words ahead of the current keyword (namely, see the words that come after a city and see if any of them are states). I tested the regex below in regex101 and it [works](https://regex101.com/r/3pgziZ/1) there.

However, when I try to incorporate it into a loop where I look to see if a city from a list shows up in a string, it doesn't work as expected (nothing is printed/there is no match found). I've tried re.escape() around city but that doesn't work, either. The regex only seems to work when "Orange" is hard-coded into it.

If anyone can find a way to improve the regex as well, that would be great. Ideally, it would be able to search for the next few words ahead until it's found three words (so, if we had a sentence like 123 Cherry Lane , Orange , \n \n \n 13238727 New Jersey is", it would isolate "New Jersey is" since those are the first three words after "Orange", even if they're not directly after it.

Thank you!

This is the code that doesn't work/doesn't print any matches, since the variable is being passed in rather than being hard-coded as "Orange":

```
import re

cities = ["Orange", "Denver"]
test_str = "The city is Orange, NJ, 07052"

for city in cities:
    regex = r"(?<=\b" + city + r")\s?(,|\.|\s){1,100}(\w{1,100})?\s?[,\.\-]?\s{1,100}?(\w{1,100})?\s{1,100}?(\w{1,100})?"
    matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        print("Match {matchNum} for {city} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum=matchNum, city=city, start=match.start(), end=match.end(), match=match.group()))

        for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
            groupNum = groupNum + 1
            print("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum=groupNum, start=match.start(groupNum), end=match.end(groupNum), group=match.group(groupNum)))
```

This is the code that works, with "Orange" is hard-coded into the regex. I want it to work such that it can take values from a loop.

```
regex = r"(?<=\bOrange)\s?(,|\.|\s){1,100}(\w{1,100})?\s?[,\.\-]?\s{1,100}?(\w{1,100})?\s{1,100}?(\w{1,100})?"

 

test_str = "The city is Orange, New Jersey"

 

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

 

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):

        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: Well you're using a different test string. Both code snippets work with the test string from the second snippet.

Comment: Both of them work after you fix your regular expression: `r"(?<=\b" + city + r")\s?(,|\.|\s){1,100}(\w{1,100})?\s?[,\.\-]?(\s{1,100})?(\w{1,100})?(\s{1,100})?(\w{1,100})?"`

Comment: @Unmitigated Ah yes, neither test string worked in the loop when I tried both. Thanks for the solution, it works for me! Could you please explain why removing those parentheses solved the problem, and why that issue wasn't happening with the original regex when "Orange" was hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `\s{1,100}` in parentheses so that `?` applies to that entire expression, making it optional. `\s{1,100}?` will always match 1-100 whitespace characters; the `?` just serves to make the matching non-greedy.

```py
r"(?<=\b" + city + r")\s?(,|\.|\s){1,100}(\w{1,100})?\s?[,\.\-]?(\s{1,100})?(\w{1,100})?(\s{1,100})?(\w{1,100})?"
```